# Dokuwiki Mediamanager attach file to a certain page

Tags: media, dokuwiki

I've the namespace structure *root:foo* with the page *root:foo:bar*. I'd like to attach a pdf document to the page *root:foo:bar* but when I open the media manager it just lets me choose the namespace foo.

Is there a way to attach a document to a certain page or can I just attach them to parent namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media files are always stored in a namespace. The media manager opens in the namespace of the page. But you can prefix your media file name with arbitrary sub namespaces. Eg. when your media manager opens in foo: you can name your file `bar:doc.pdf` and it will be uploaded as `foo:bar:doc.pdf` creating a new namespace `foo:bar:`.